# I need to finalize this MySQL multiple table JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have `entires`, `equipments`, `brands`, `times` and `seasons`.

**entries**:

- id
- time
- equipment_1
- equipment_2

**equipments**:

- id
- id_brand

**brands**:

- id
- name

**times**:

- id
- id_season

**seasons**:

- id
- name

My actual SQL query is:

```
SELECT entries.*, times.id_season AS id_season
FROM entries, seasons
WHERE entries.time = times.id
```

But in the final query I need the next information that I don't know how to obtain it:

1. The name for each entries.equipment_ as equipment_1_name and equipment_2_name which is set in brands.name.
2. The name of the season as season_name.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have normalized data.  This avoid costly cartesian joins.  I never use cartesian joins myself, although there are some cases where they are useful.  Not here, though.

```
SELECT
  entries.*,
  times.id_seasons AS id_season,
  b1.name AS equipment_1_name,
  b2.name AS equipment_2_name,
  seasons.name AS season_name
FROM entries
LEFT JOIN equipments AS equipments_1
  ON equipments_1.id = entries.equipment_1
LEFT JOIN brands AS brands_1 
  ON brands_1.id = equipments_1.id_brand
LEFT JOIN equipments AS equipments_2 
  ON equipments_2.id = entries.equipment_2
LEFT JOIN brands AS brands_2
  ON brands_2.id = equipments_2.id_brand
LEFT JOIN times 
  ON times.id = entries.time
LEFT JOIN seasons 
  ON seasons.id = times.id_season;
```